Why is the embedding of a well-pointed sapce into the reduced cone a cofibration?
$X$ is a well-pointed space if there exists a point $x_0$ in $X$ such that the inclusion $x_0\rightarrow X$ is a cofibration. And the reduced cone $C_*X$ of $X$ is defined as $C_*X=X\times I/(X\times\{0\}\cup x_0 \times I)$. I have seen in many textbooks claiming that the natural embedding $i_1:X\rightarrow C_*(X) $ given by $i_1(x)=(x,1)$ is a cofibration. I think it must an easy conclusion but I cant find a way to prove it. I have tried to find a explicit homotopy, i.e. given $F$ defined on $C_*(X)\times \{0\}\cup X\times I$, extend it explicitly to $C_*(X)\times I$. But I have no idea at all about how to do this.

Hint: The embedding $X\rightarrow C_{\ast}X$ is a cobase change of $X\times\partial I\cup\{x_0\}\times I\rightarrow X\times I$.

Well, actually that's exactly what I am looking for. One commutative diagram shows everything. Thank you.
